# Copy ID from nested element to its top parent using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, label

I have the following situation in my HTML created by a plugin:

```
<div class="form-controls">
    <div class="form__field ">
        <div class="preferences__notification">
            <label id="user_comment" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-controls">
    <div class="form__field ">
        <div class="preferences__notification">
            <label id="wall_post" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above HTML is around 20 repeating elements long and I am trying to call the individual main parents `form-controls` so I can add unique CSS or jQuery. The only unique identity in this HTML is on the nested `label`. So there are 20x unique `<label>` IDs. So I was wondering how I could get the `label` id copied to its top parent `form-controls' with jQuery, so the outcome would be for the first one:

```
<div id="user_comment" class="form-controls">etc</div>
```

---

**Update Solution**
My initial request to add the same `id` from the `<label>` into the top parent is HTML wise not clever to do. So the accepted answer is okay, but not ideal. To make it more HTML valid, I have chosen to take the `<label id=` name as an additional class for the top parent. So ultimate solution will be this:

```
jQuery(".form-controls").each(function() {
    var label_id_name = jQuery(this).find('label').attr('id');
    jQuery(this).addClass(label_id_name);
});
```

And HTML outcome:

```
<div class="form-controls user_comment">
    <div class="form__field ">
        <div class="preferences__notification">
            <label id="user_comment" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-controls wall_post">
    <div class="form__field ">
        <div class="preferences__notification">
            <label id="wall_post" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If that HTML is repeated 20 times then your problem is that `id` attributes have to be unique within the DOM. Try using classes instead with DOM traversal, or access then by their index. Which is best in this case depends on exactly when and how you want to add the styling to these elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I do not understand, there is a unique ID, that's the `<label>`, as explained in my question. So 20x unique label ID's.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you make a snippet for it? Because we are not able to understand your problem statement.

Comment: @Demian you state that you have that same HTML repeated 20 times, hence the `id` attributes you're using will be duplicated as well, which is not valid HTML.

Comment: @BharatChoudhary I assume you meant to send that to the person that asked the question, not me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I understand your concern, however this HTML is php generated structure, so I cannot influence how it's build, but if you suggest to have the unique ID name as the top parent's extra class name, that could improve your concern.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, hahaha, I'm sorry, I tagged you there!

Comment: I'd suggest changing the PHP then, as there's no excuse for having invalid code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's a premade plugin, I'd have done that if that was possible. Sorry these are all comments with obvious answers, and doesn't bring anyone further.

Comment: I agree, however the solution you've accepted may solve your immediate issue but will result in others later. This is why I'm trying to understand what you're trying to do, so that you can have a robust working solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes you are correct that the idea of adding the same id for the top parent is not a solution. That's why I have chosen to add the id name of the label as a class in the top parent. So it won't cause conflicts. A question or a desired outcome might not always be the best solution, but it might need a different approach. That's why we are here to lead each other into the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER UPDATE:** - Copy label ID to div class

This is the preferred way to accomplish this to avoid conflicting ID'S

```
jQuery(".form-controls").each(function() {
    var label_id_name = jQuery(this).find('label').attr('id');
    jQuery(this).addClass(label_id_name);
});
```

**OLD ANSWER** - copying ID from label to div.

You can copy the id attribute of each nested label by looping through all div with form-control class.

```
$(".form-controls").each(function()
                        {

  var label_id = $(this).find('label').attr("id");
  $(this).attr("id", label_id);

});
```

In your code the outcome will be:

```
<div class="form-controls" id="user_comment">
    <div class="form__field ">
        <div class="preferences__notification">
            <label id="user_comment" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-controls" id="wall_post">
    <div class="form__field ">
        <div class="preferences__notification">
            <label id="wall_post" class="form-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will loop each div with the class of `.form-controls` and change it's ID to it's label descendant ID.

Keep in mind this is not the best practice since id's are meant to be unique. Consider using class instead.

You can also add the following code at the end of the loop to remove the label's ID after copying them.

```
$(this).find('label').removeAttr("id");
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: is it perhaps better if I choose to have the `<label>` ID as the class in the top parent, so it's a unique attribute and not a conflicting attribute? Is this also possible? So it will be `$(this).addClass(label_id);`

Comment: Yep that's a valid way to avoid conflicting your ID's. Although to avoid confusion for yourself it may be better to call the class in a different name altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go! I have pasted code below, please have a look.

```js
const addIDToParent = ele => {
      for (var i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
       let getId = $(ele[i]).find('label').attr('id');
       $(ele[i]).attr('id', getId);
      }
     };
     
     addIDToParent($('.form-controls'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="form-controls">
        <div class="form__field ">
            <div class="preferences__notification">
                <label id="user_comment" class="form-label">User Comment</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-controls">
        <div class="form__field ">
            <div class="preferences__notification">
                <label id="wall_post" class="form-label">Wall Post</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```